# Sql server 2008 : Query to search for today's date within overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, timespan, date-range, overlapping-matches

[image]

I have the above table wherein I need to get NoteIndx matching today's date. Just for testing, assume today is 2013/06/02 (Jun 2,2013) and that would get me two records with noteindx  93105 and 104044.

But the correct value here is 104044 as I need to choose the one that has shortest datespan of STRTDATE and ENDDATE.

I am trying with various sql queries but not getting correct result so far.

Can anyone help me with the best possible query to get above results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select top 1 n.*
from notes n
where cast('2013-06-02' as date) >= strtdate and
      cast('2013-06-02' as date) < enddate + 1
order by enddate - strtdate;
```

This does not use `between` because your dates are stored as `datetime` -- this always introduces the possibility of their being a time portion on the date.

If you want today's date, then use `getdate()` instead of `cast('2013-06-02' as date)`.

Comment: +1 Wanted to add that `BETWEEN` can also be used for the date comparison.

Comment: @user2989408 . . . Between would work for the date constant (assuming that there is no time component on the dates).  It would not work for `getdate()` where `enddate` is today.